# Undefined Variable in Laravel8 Possible typo

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to pass a variable from Controller to blade view.

So there is my Controller :

```php
     public function index_ajout_projet() {
            $clients = Client::whereIn('id_filiale',[0,  Auth::user()->id_filiale])->get();
            $agences_conseil = AgenceConseil::all();
            $agences_casting = Agence_Casting::all();
          
        return view('Projet.ajout_projet', [ 'clients' => $clients ],[ 'agences_conseil' => $agences_conseil ],['agences_casting'=>$agences_casting]);
    }
```

There is my view :

```html
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputState">Agence de Production</label>
            <select id="id_agence_production" class="form-control" name="id_agence_production">
                <option selected>Choose...</option>
                @foreach($agences_conseil as $agence_conseil)
                    <option data-id="{{$agence_conseil->id_agence_production}}" value="{{$agence_conseil->id_agence_production}}">{{$agence_conseil->agence_production}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputState">Agence de Casting</label>
            <select id="id_agence_casting" class="form-control" name="id_agence_casting">
                <option selected>Choose...</option>
                    @foreach($agences_casting as $agence_casting)
                    <option data-id="{{$agence_casting->id_agence_casting}}" value="{{$agence_casting->id_agence_casting}}">{{$agence_casting->agence_casting}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I get the followin error :

```
ErrorException
Undefined variable: agences_casting (View: D:\Projet_Cast_Infl\resources\views\Projet\ajout_projet.blade.php)
Possible typo $agences_casting
Did you mean $agences_conseil?
```

I don't know what is the problem , I did the same for `$agences_conseil` And it works. Why it doesn't know the `$agences_casting` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 4 ways to pass data to view

#### 1 - by using compact

```
return view('Projet.ajout_projet', compact(
    'clients', 
    'agences_conseil', 
    'agences_casting'
);
```

#### 2 - by using array

```
return view('Projet.ajout_projet', [
    'clients' => $clients, 
    'agences_conseil' => $agences_conseil, 
    'agences_casting' => $agences_casting
]);
```

#### 3 - by using with()

```
return view('Projet.ajout_projet')->with([
    'clients' => $clients, 
    'agences_conseil' => $agences_conseil, 
    'agences_casting' => $agences_casting
]);
```

#### 4 - by using multiple with()

```
return view('Projet.ajout_projet')
    ->with('clients', $clients)
    ->with('agences_conseil', $agences_conseil)
    ->with('agences_casting', $agences_casting);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning data to view not as single array .Instead you are passing multiple `parameters` to `view method`.

```
return view('Projet.ajout_projet', 
         [ 'clients' => $clients ],
         [ 'agences_conseil' => $agences_conseil ], 
         ['agences_casting'=>$agences_casting]
       );
```

So if you see view method

`view($view = null, $data = [], $mergeData = [])`

it accepts `3 params` but you have passed `4 parameters` to `view method`. So `second` and `third` parameter will merge and last one will ignore. So it throw error.

Possible way to passing data as already explained by @AkashKumarVerma